# Problema ao utilizar LabelFor Razor MVC 3 + C#

Tags: c#, html, mvc, razor

Estou com o seguinte erro na minha `View`: ao eu passar `@class="classe boot-strap"` não é utilizada, mesmo passando na `View` dentro do parâmetro `@class` ele insiste em utilizar o `'text-box single-line'`, logo abaixo vou deixa os trechos do código.

Código `Razor`:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataManutencao, new { @class = "span2 control-label" })
```

Código HTML do debugador do Chrome:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Data Agendamento must be a date." data-val-required="Este campo é obrigatório!" id="DataManutencao" name="DataManutencao" type="datetime" value="01/01/0001">
```

Comment: Tente trocar o `EditorFor` por `TextBoxFor`. 
No MVC 3, o `EditorFor` não trabalha bem com atributos HTML.

Comment: Já cheguei a usar o textBoxFor, funciona, porém não consigo utilizar o data annotations do model, tem como resolver este problema ou somente passando os atributos HTML através das tags mesmo?